# How to capture response from the server after page has been reloaded? Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, payment

I have a page with a form with fields, required for payment system. Submitting this form, I call service to send request to this system. As the result, I am redirected to payment system page, where I can make payment. When the payment is done, I am redirected again to my page, where the request was send from. 
The problem is that I cannot capture response from the payment server in my component, despite the fact that I can see that reponse in the Network tab of dev tools.

Method in service

```
sendXMLToFondy(request: RequestFondyViewModel): Observable<any> {
    let body = ` 
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <request>
                      <response_url>${request.response_url}</response_url>
                      <server_callback_url> ${request.server_callback_url}</server_callback_url>
                      <order_id> ${request.order_id}</order_id>
                      <order_desc> ${request.order_desc}</order_desc>
                      <currency>${request.currency}</currency>
                      <amount>${request.amount}</amount>
                      <signature>${request.signature}</signature>
                      <merchant_id>${request.merchant_id}</merchant_id>
                    </request>        
                `;
    return this._http.post("https://api.fondy.eu/api/checkout/url/", body)           
        .map((response: Response) => {               
            let res = response.text();
            return res;
        });
}
```

And that is how I call service in my component

```
 sendRequest(): void {    
        this._donateService.sendXMLToFondy(this.fondyPayModel).
            subscribe((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            });     
    }
```

Operators, which I put inside .map(in service) and .subscribe(in component), are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I also faced the same issue. I resolved that issue by implementing a callback function in my service like:

```
public paymentGateway(request: Customer, callback) {
     this.http.post(url, request).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((res) => {
        return callback(res);
     });
}
```

and in component the code would be like this:

```
public onPaymentGateway(request: Customer) {
    this.service.paymentGateway(request, (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  
I tried your method but it did not work for me. 
It looks like that response from the server comes before my component is created. So, there is nothing that could catch this response at the moment, when it arrives.